# Why $B= \{(x,y)|x=0,y\neq 0\} $ in $(\mathbb R^2,d_2)$ is not open and closed

Tags: metric-spaces

Can someone explain to me why the the subset $B= \{(x,y)|x=0,y\neq 0\} $ in $(\mathbb R^2,d_2)$, is EDIT: not closed? I understand why it's not open. If someone could explain it simply to me that would be great!

Comment: It's not closed...$(0,0)$ is a limit point but does not belong to $B$.

Comment: Typo sorry! Ah I see, can I ask why is $(0,0)$ a limit point? Is that assuming $x$ and $y$ are approaching 0?

Comment: Is $d_2$ the usual metric?

Answer (score 1):

You know that this set is closed if **R-B** is open. The set is open if there is $B(x,r)|r>0 \subseteq R-B$. You can see that if you take the point $(0,0)\in R-B$ there is't a ball that is incluid on it.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence of points $(0,1/n),$ where $n\in\mathbb{N},$ is contained in $B,$ but this sequence converges to a limit, namely $(0,0),$ and the limit point is not contained in $B.$ Hence $B$ is not closed.

Answer (score 0):

Our set is the whole y axis except (0,0). A set is open with a metric if and only if its interior is equal to the set. We can see that the interior of the set is null (there aren't any balls centered at $(o,y), y$ other than $0$, contained in the set). Moreover, a set is closed if and only if it is equal to its closure. It is easy to see by definition, that the closure of our set is the whole y axis. As a result, the set is neither open nor closed.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon>0.$ Then $B_\epsilon (0,0)=\{(x,y):\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\epsilon\}.$ Also for any given $\epsilon>0$ choose $(x,y)\in B$ such that $x=0,y=\epsilon/2.$ Then for any $\epsilon$ we have $\sqrt{0^2+\epsilon^2/4}=\epsilon/2<\epsilon.$

 Now you can see that $(0,0)$ is indeed a limit point.